# Finding file changes between git branches under a subfolder

Tags: git

I have two branches `main` and `R2` that was branched from it a long time ago. On both branches there were many changes and sometimes code from `main` was merged manually (copy-paste or cherry pick) into `R2`.
Both branches have a subfolder `src`.

Now I want to find all the changes under `src` that are in commits to `R2` and not in `main`.
But I would like it not as a list of commits but as the final code fragments parts that were changed, and on which file.

Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can see all differences between files with command

> git diff R2 main

Comment: Thanks, but this will show changes from R2 to main and from main to R2, i want only the changes that are in R2 and not existing in main.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. According to docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1) correct way to see changes introduced by branch R2 would be (for your branches) git diff main...R2